# Is ECC multiplication over real number also one-way?

Tags: elliptic-curves

ECC multiplication over GF(p) is clearly one-way.

How about ECC over real number?

Is ECC division over real number also practically impossible?

Comment: I don't believe ECC would even work over real numbers.

Comment: @forest Could you explain more about that in detail?

Comment: Arithmetic over real numbers is not efficiently computable (if it is computable at all). Also, floating-point numbers do not form a field.

Comment: Well, it is of course possible to canonically encode a real number to binary, and then use an integer representation of that number to perform a calculation. Of course, it depends on your requirements if this is useful at all as the real number would loose its original meaning within the cryptosystem.

Comment: I think the last part of the answer of fgrieu should answer your question on one-wayness / security. Feel free to post a more specific followup question if anything is unclear on that. Note that we have to decide on a particular scheme before we can answer if it is one-way or not. Without pinpointing a particular scheme - as there doesn't seem to be a commonly used one - the question cannot be answered.